# Laravel 5 + jQuery Mask Plugin Inserting [object Object] Into Inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel-5, jquery-mask

I am using the jQuery Mask Plugin (available [here](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)) to mask certain inputs as such:

```
<input type="text" name="phone" value="{{ old('phone', $person->phone) }}" data-mask="(000) 000-0000" required>
<input type="text" name="zip" value="{{ old('zip', $person->zip) }}" data-mask="00000" required>
```

For the most part, it has been working just fine. However, recent changes in the project code have resulted in a peculiar error: when you click on an input with a set mask, it's instantly filled in with "[object Object]". This input can't be deleted, and there's no error messages indicating what any possible issues resulting in it.

Does anyone know what the plugin is doing, and how I can possibly fix it?

EDIT: For further context, the project is built on Laravel 5.4. I am initially filling the inputs with values from a database object and am saving the inputs onto that object on upload. The "phone" and "zip" attributes are saved in the database as integers.

EDIT 2: My current browser is Google Chrome. The HTML is rendering like such:

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" value="2147483647" data-mask="(000) 000-0000" required="" autocomplete="off" maxlength="14">
</div>
```

This rendering doesn't change when I click on it (thus changing it to "[object Object]"), and and no errors are printing on the "Console" tab.

Comment: The behaviour implies that an object is being coerced to a string somewhere in your code. Please show the JS that's instantiating the masking library

Comment: I've clarified one particular piece in the OP. Not sure that helps, or if you need me to expand further on it.

Comment: Could you add the rendered html? what you see when you use the browser inspect tools

Comment: OP has been updated with the rendering.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use this the jQuery-mask-plugin library in the laravel, I share my solution.

Register form

```php
 <!-- resources/views/user/create.blade.php -->
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('script')
<script>
    $(document).ready(function($){
        $('#cpf').mask('999.999.999-99');
   });
</script>
@endsection

@section('content')
<form class="form-group" action="{{ action('UserController@store', 0) }}" method="post">
    @csrf
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label>CPF</label><br>
        <input class="form-control" id="cpf" type="text" name="cpf" required><br>
    </div>
</form>

@stop
```

```php
<!doctype html>
<head>
</head>
 <!-- resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php -->
<body>
    <div id="app">
        @yield('content')
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.16/jquery.mask.js"
        integrity="sha256-yE5LLp5HSQ/z+hJeCqkz9hdjNkk1jaiGG0tDCraumnA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
<!-- Carrega o Script Personalizado na Página aqui -->
    @yield("script")

</body>
</html>
```